Instrumental variables with felm in R?
I am trying to run a fixed effects regression on the following panel dataset, using event as an instrumental variable for ms, using the felm function from the lfe package:
year<-c(1961 ,1962, 1961, 1962)
country<-c("A", "B", "A", "B")
gdp<-c(5.4, 5.9, 5.2, 5.4)
ms<-c(4.1, 4.1, 8.6, 6.3)
event<-c(1,0,0,1)
df1<-tibble(year, country, gdp, ms, event)

fit <- lfe::felm(gdp ~ ms | country | 0 | country, ms~event, df1)
summary(fit)

However, running the above regression doesn't work, and instead gives me an error. How could I change these lines so that it uses the instrumental variable in the fixed effect regression?

The error comes from the second argument in your lfe::felm(gdp ~ ms | country | 0 | country, ms~event, df1). You are getting an error because you are fitting 2 formula expressions in the model gdp ~ ms | country | 0 | country and ms~event. The function does only accepts one formula. I think it might be helpful to fit two models since you're trying to do an instrument variable analysis? (i'm not the expert, you might have a better chance at cross validated.) Some thing like fit1 <- felm(ms~event, df1) and fit2 <- felm(your_formula, df1).

For the second fit, you would want to use the predicted values from your fit1 as a predictor in your fit2.
